# Dynamic pattern matching with MATCH failing

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm creating a dashboard with Dash on which I want a variable number of graphs with associated dropdowns underneath each other. The dropdowns control an aspect of the graph (how it's sorted, but this is unimportant). Here is the code:

```
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State, MATCH
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from app.plots import get_product_breakdown_bar_chart
from .selectors import get_product_selection_checklist, get_impact_parameter_selection_checklist, get_product_to_sort_on_dropdown, DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CHECKLIST_ID, DEFAULT_IMPACT_PARAMETER_CHECKLIST_ID, DEFAULT_PRODUCTS, DEFAULT_IMPACT_PARAMETERS

def get_selectors_pane():
  selectors_row = dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(
      [get_product_selection_checklist()],
      width = 6
    ),
    dbc.Col(
      [get_impact_parameter_selection_checklist()],
      width = 6
    )
  ])
  labels_row = dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(
      [dbc.Label("Products:", html_for = DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CHECKLIST_ID)],
      width = 6
    ),
    dbc.Col(
      [dbc.Label("Impact parameters: ", html_for = DEFAULT_IMPACT_PARAMETER_CHECKLIST_ID)],
      width = 6
    )
  ])
  return html.Div([
    labels_row,
    selectors_row
  ])

saved_sorted_on_states = {}
selected_products = DEFAULT_PRODUCTS
def render_graph_rows(selected_products, selected_impact_parameters):
  def sov(impact_parameter):
    if impact_parameter in saved_sorted_on_states:
      if saved_sorted_on_states[impact_parameter] in selected_products:
        return saved_sorted_on_states[impact_parameter]
      else:
        saved_sorted_on_states.pop(impact_parameter)
        return selected_products[0]
    else:
      return selected_products[0]
 
  rows = []
  for s_ip in selected_impact_parameters:
    sort_on_dropdown_id = {"type": "sort-on-dropdown", "index": s_ip}
    ip_graph_id = {"type": "impact-parameter-graph", "index": s_ip}
    rows.append(
      html.Div([
        dbc.Row([
          dbc.Col([dbc.Label("Sort on:", html_for = sort_on_dropdown_id)], width = 2),
          dbc.Col([get_product_to_sort_on_dropdown(sort_on_dropdown_id, sov(s_ip))], width = 10)
        ]),
        dbc.Row([
          dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(
              id = ip_graph_id,
              figure = get_product_breakdown_bar_chart(s_ip, selected_products, sov(s_ip))
            )
          ], width = 12)
        ])
      ])
    )
  return rows

content_layout = html.Div(
  id = "content",
  children = [
    get_selectors_pane(),
    html.Div(
      id = "graph-grid",
      children = render_graph_rows(DEFAULT_PRODUCTS, DEFAULT_IMPACT_PARAMETERS)
    )
  ],
  style = {
    "margin-left": "14rem",
    "margin-right": "2rem",
    "padding": "2rem 1rem",
  }
)

def register_callback(app):
  def sort_graph_callback(value, index):
    global saved_sorted_on_states
    saved_sorted_on_states[index] = value
    return (get_product_breakdown_bar_chart(index, selected_products, value), )
  app.callback(
    [Output({"type": "impact-parameter-graph", "index": MATCH}, "figure")],
    [Input({"type": "sort-on-dropdown", "index": MATCH}, "value")],
    [State({"type": "sort-on-dropdown", "index": MATCH}, "id")]
  )(sort_graph_callback)

  def new_master_selection_callback(s_ps, s_ips):
    global selected_products
    selected_products = s_ps
    return (render_graph_rows(s_ps, s_ips), )
  app.callback(
    [Output("graph-grid", "children")],
    [Input(DEFAULT_PRODUCT_CHECKLIST_ID, "value"), Input(DEFAULT_IMPACT_PARAMETER_CHECKLIST_ID, "value")]
  )(new_master_selection_callback)
```

The problem is that the sort_graph_callback defined on line 86 never gets called. This callback is supposed to connect dynamically added graphs with dynamically added dropdowns associated to them. But when I select a different option in such a dropdown nothing happens to the associated graph and the callback doesn't get called at all. I know this from setting breakpoints in them. I have verified that the correct id's are assigned to the rendered graph and dropdown components.

(Please note that I'm registering the callbacks in a peculiar way due to code organization reasons. I have verified that this is not the cause of the issue)

I have no clue anymore how to debug this issue. In my development environment pattern matching callback examples from the official documentation work just fine. Is there anything I'm missing?

Thank you so much in advance,
Joshua

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No. Only some generic React warnings I see in every Dash app I open.

Comment: There is (or at least should be) an error In the callback, if `index` corresponds to the `id` of the dropdown that fires the event, then it is a dict `{'type': 'sort-on-dropdown', 'index': <index>}`, so this line `saved_sorted_on_states[index] = value` should throw "_TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'_".

Comment: Thanks Eric. I fixed that, but the callback is still not triggered.

Comment: I have noticed that the problem is related to the number of dynamic components. if I have little the callback gets fired fine.